# Laravel migration create custom foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I am creating migration in laravel, where at some point I need to create custom foreign key  name in database. I have searched this solution but there is nothing similar to my problem.

I want to add columns for `names` table that contain birth_city_id, birth_state_id and birth_country_id. Apart from this I also want to add death_city_id, death_state_id, death_counrty_id.

Error:

```
Migrating: 2021_11_21_130238_create_names_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `names` add constraint `birth_city_id` foreign key (`city_id`) references `cities` ())

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:703
    699▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    700▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    701▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    702▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 703▕             throw new QueryException(
    704▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    705▕             );
    706▕         }
    707▕     }

      +9 vendor frames 
  10  database/migrations/2021_11_21_130238_create_names_table.php:37
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()

      +21 vendor frames 
  32  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Below is the related article but that does't work.
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-migration-custom-foreign-key-name-exampleexample.html

```
Schema::create('names', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('fname')->nullable();
            $table->string('mname')->nullable();
            $table->string('lname')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('nickname')->nullable();
            $table->string('height')->nullable();
            $table->string('gender',15)->nullable();
            $table->date('dob')->comment('Date of Birth')->nullable();
            $table->date('dod')->comment('Date of Death')->nullable();   
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('state_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');              
            $table->foreign('city_id','birth_city_id')->nullable()->refrences('id')->on('cities');
            $table->foreign('state_id','birth_state_id')->nullable()->refrences('id')->on('states');
            $table->foreign('country_id','birth_country_id')->nullable()->refrences('id')->on('countries');            
            $table->text('mini_bio')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_active')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Table cities, states, countries are already exist in database.

```
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('code',10)->nullable();
        $table->foreignId('state_id')->constrained();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: I think you have wrongly coded the Migration. You should write the column first and then write the foreign relationship separately.

Comment: @nagidi I have tried that too but it's throwing an error.

Comment: put the foreign at the bottom, and instead of foreign()->references etc. you can do this in laravel 8: $table->foreignId('your_id')->constrained('your table')->nullable();
Nullable also should be at the back.

Comment: Try removing the `nullable` from the `foreign` constraint and adding it to the `unsignedBigInteger`

Comment: @bgeertsema2000 If you read the documentation nullable() must come before constrained() like this: `$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained();`.

Comment: @HemantKumar you are not using `foreignId` here though you are using `foreign`

Comment: Yeah my bad, typo :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the method [foreign](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_foreign) take string|array as $columns as its first argument, then a string as the index name ...

anyway, if you want to make multi references to another table, you should have multi-column for that:

```
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('birth_city_id')->nullable();;
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('death_city_id')->nullable();;
 $table->foreign('birth_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
 $table->foreign('death_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
```

by the way, I found a typo in your code, it `references` not `refrences`

Comment: what would even be easier is writing it as foreignId('some_id')->constrained('table')->nullable();
Just like docs say.

Comment: I think `birth_city_id` is meant to be the index name .

Comment: @OMR When we execute you this lines of code it will filed to create foreign key constrained because we did not mention `city_id` as foreign key. My point is I want to store birth city, state, country id in this table along with death city, state and country id.
That is the reason I want the column name different.

Comment: mmm , I have updated my answer to fit, please tell me if it useful

Comment: That typo was easy to miss

Comment: @OMR Thanks, that works except the nullable() will be like:  
 `$table->unsignedBigInteger('birth_city_id')->nullable();
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('death_city_id')->nullable();
  $table->foreign('birth_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
  $table->foreign('death_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');`

Comment: ok, you got it!